# BIgquery sql eliminating error record from the below records

Tags: mysql, sql, google-bigquery

I'm seeing few below sample duplicate records in more than 200k records

```
YEAR|SEASON|DM_NBR|DM_DESC|BYR_NBR|LAST_NM|DEPT_ID|DEPT_DESC|Market Cluster|OFC_NBR|Month|FSCL_MN_ID|Capacity|Total|MINIMUM_CAPACITY|Clear_max|Floor_Capacity|Stock_Capacity|Store_Capacity|Max_Capacity|Space_Max_Capacity
 
2021|SPRING|1|HOME|8|FURNITURE|23|ARTIST|COLD|1990|OCTOBER|202110|Normal_Capacity|0|0|0|0|0|0|0|0
2021|SPRING|1|HOME|8|FURNITURE|23|ARTIST|COLD|1990|OCTOBER|202110|Normal_Capacity|490|490|0|0|0|0|0|0
```

Whereas i am trying to eliminate 1st row in result and retrieve only second row as it is valid record.

Below is the query which I have tried where as I'm still getting the two rows in the output

```
select * from (SELECT * FROM `project_id.backup_dataset.capacity_assortment` where date(lod_tmst)='2021-11-09') a
INNER JOIN
    (SELECT OFC_NBR,YEAR,DEPT_ID,MONTH,MAX(Total) AS tot_capc,max(MINIMUM_CAPACITY) as min_capc
    FROM `kohls-bda-prd.backup_dataset.capacity_assortment` b where date(b.lod_tmst)='2021-11-09'
    GROUP BY OFC_NBR,YEAR,DEPT_ID,MONTH) b 
ON a.OFC_NBR = b.OFC_NBR 
AND a.YEAR= b.YEAR
AND a.DEPT_ID= b.DEPT_ID
AND a.MONTH= b.MONTH
```

Can someone please tell me what is wrong with my query and help me with correct query please.

Comment: It's not completely clear what you mean by duplicate (which fields are telling you a row is duplicate?) and the logic for identifying the correct row (in your example you want to keep the 2nd row, but what is the exact requirement?)

I think that by using a GROUP BY clause or ROW_NUMBER function you can achieve the goal. But before telling you I need to fully unferstand the problem

Comment: Check this out - [link](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/streaming-data-into-bigquery#manually_removing_duplicates)

Comment: @Gumaz please compare  Total|MINIMUM_CAPACITY for first row it is 0|0 whereas for second it is 490|490 i need to get only this in the result set.

Comment: This is clear. But is this the only case? Every duplicate matches this exact form (has total and minimum_capacity to 0)? If you want to get rid of those rows you could just filtering them with a WHERE condition

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple group by may solve the issue:

```
SELECT
  YEAR,
  SEASON,
  DM_NBR,
  DM_DESC,
  BYR_NBR,
  LAST_NM,
  DEPT_ID,
  DEPT_DESC,
  MarketCluster,
  OFC_NBR,
  Month,
  FSCL_MN_ID,
  CAPACITY,
  MAX(Total) AS Total,
  MAX(MINIMUM_CAPACITY),
  MAX(Clear_max),
  MAX(Floor_Capacity),
  MAX(Stock_Capacity),
  MAX(Store_Capacity),
  MAX(Max_Capacity),
  MAX(Space_Max_Capacity),
FROM `project_id.backup_dataset.capacity_assortment`
GROUP BY
  YEAR,
  SEASON,
  DM_NBR,
  DM_DESC,
  BYR_NBR,
  LAST_NM,
  DEPT_ID,
  DEPT_DESC,
  MarketCluster,
  OFC_NBR,
  Month,
  FSCL_MN_ID,
  CAPACITY
```

Assuming you only want to keep the maximum number of the various quantities.

Moreover, if your "duplicates" always has 0s you could simply remove them using `WHERE Total>0` (eventually adding conditions on each required field).

In the end it's still not clear to me whether you have a duplication problem or just want to get rid of "invalid" rows.

However, for the exact problem the query I posted will work but I'm answering based on the assumption that you want to keep rows with the highest number of total, capacity, etc. which may not be true in all cases.